# Bash - Remote Library

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting

We're two student working on a Bash Tools Box, and we come across a problem :

Our local script use functions, stocked in two local libraries.

Our script uses functions inside the first library, and this last uses functions inside the second one library.

Script <-- Library1 <-- Library2

We can't fusion the two libraries in one.

We actually use this command to run our script on a remote computer :

```
ssh login@remoteIP bash < ~/script.sh
```

The question is : How to set in the script the library location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `.` command in order to include external libraries. Yes, the command is simply called `.` - a literal dot. In *library1.sh* add at the top:

```
. /path/to/library2.sh
```

In *script.sh* add at the top:

```
. /path/to/library1.sh
```

I would recommend to use absolute paths since relative paths. If you use relative paths, you need to make sure that they are relative to one of your `$PATH` entries otherwise they would be relative to the current folder where `script.sh` gets executed.

---

Btw, there is also the `source` command which is doing excatly the same as the dot command. Both of them are bash builtins.

Type `help .` or `help source` to get help.

Comment: You could just as well source both from the script. The net effect will be the same. No need to modify an existing "library".

Comment: If library1 depends on library2 the source should happen in library1 not in the script.sh. Also the library is *still under development* so why not changing it?

Comment: Everything is working in local, the problem show up when we run this script on a remote computer :
This script try to use function stored in on the local computer, but can't "back" to it; it doesn't work even if we specify the IP of the local computer in in the source command

Comment: Of course you need to copy both libraries and the script to another computer. Isn't this obvious?

Comment: We can't install anything on the remote computer, that's why everything is done by ssh from a computer with the bash script, and the 2 libraries :/

We have one local machine with the scripts and the 2 libraries, and a remote machine with nothing set on it, and nothing could be set on it

Answer (score 0):

Embed your Library# code in your script using [`bashpp`](https://github.com/iwonbigbro/bashpp).

Replace your `.` calls with `#include` and then run it through `bashpp`:

```
bashpp ~/script.sh | ssh login@remoteIP bash -s
```