# How to use a source file while executing a script on a remote machine over SSH

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am running a bash script on a remote machine over SSH.

```
ssh -T $DBHOST2 'bash -s' < $DIR/script.sh <arguments>
```

Within the script I am using a source file for defining functions used in the script `script.sh`.

```
DIR=`dirname $0`      # to get the location where the script is located
echo "Directory is $DIR"
. $DIR/source.bashrc  # source file
```

But since the source file is not present in the remote machine it results in an error.

```
Directory is .
./source.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

I can always define the functions along with the main script rather than using a source file, but I was wondering is there any way to use a separate source file.

Edit : Neither the source file nor the script is located in the remote machine.

Comment: I should note that neither the source file nor the script is located on the remote machine.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue few years ago and I never got a reply, hope you will have more luck ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717672/bash-remote-library

Answer (score 2):

Here are to ways to this - both only requiring one `ssh` session.

### Option 1: Use `tar` to copy your scripts to the server

```
tar cf - $DIR/script.sh $DIR/source.bashrc | ssh $DBHOST2 "tar xf -; bash $DIR/script.sh <arguments>"
```

This 'copies' your scripts to your `$DBHOST2` and executes them there.

### Option 2: Use `bashpp` to include all code in one script

If copying files onto `$DBHOST2` is not an option, use [`bashpp`](https://github.com/iwonbigbro/bashpp).

Replace your `.` calls with `#include` and then run it through `bashpp`:

```
bashpp $DIR/script.sh | ssh $DBHOST2 bash -s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -T $DBHOST2 'bash -s' <<< $(cat source_file $DIR/script.sh)
```

Comment: How do i use the source_file from within the script. Is `source "source_file"` sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The following acheives what I am trying to do.

1.Copy the source file to remote machine.

```
scp $DIR/source.bashrc $DBHOST2:./
```

2.[Execute the local script with arguments on the remote machine via SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments)

```
ssh $DBHOST2 "bash -s" -- < $DIR/script.sh <arguments>
```

3. Copy remote logfile `logfile.log` to local file `dbhost2.log` and remove the source file and logfile from the remote machine

```
ssh $DBHOST2 "cat logfile.log; rm -f source.bashrc logfile.log" > dbhost.log
```